Почему не работает условие цикла while?
Не могу понять почему при выполнении цикла while программа при повторном вводе данных, которые соответствуют условию, выдает ответ, который должен выходить при НЕсоответствии условию.
password = input()

numbers = '1234567890'
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
title_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
specials = '!@#$%^&*()-+'
vocabulary = numbers + letters + title_letters + specials

condition1 = 0
condition2 = 0
condition3 = 0
condition4 = 0
condition5 = 0
condition6 = 0

for letter in password:
    while letter not in vocabulary:
        print('Prohibited symbol')
        password = input()
    else:
        condition1 = 1



if len(password) >= 12:
    condition2 = 1

for letter in password:
    if letter in numbers:
        condition3 = 1
    if letter in letters:
        condition4 = 1
    if letter in title_letters:
        condition5 = 1
    if letter in specials:
        condition6 = 1

if condition1 and condition2 and condition3 and condition4 and condition5 and condition6 == 1:
    print('Password is secure')
else:
    print('Password is insecure')


Что-то тут ничего не понятно, внутри цикла while letter not in vocabulary: у вас никогда не меняются ни переменная letter, ни переменная vocabulary — а это означает, что если цикл while сработал, то у него нет никаких возможностей завершиться и он будет работать вечно

Да, спасибо, я увидел, что он будет бесконечным.
Я хотел сделать проверку надежности пароля, и при вводе запрещенного символа программа должна выводить "Prohibited symbol", после чего давать возможность повторно ввести password, а затем заново запустить проверку. Думаю, что можно это зациклить с помощью while, но никак не пойму как именно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Куда проще просто написать чего Вы хотите. Проверять состав пароля по определённым правилам? Я уверен, что код для этого может быть короче и понятнее. Именно это проблема - попытки реализовать слишком заумную логику.

Условие было следующим:
Вводится пароль.
Далее он должен пройти проверку на надежность.
Условия:

Не менее 12 символов
Должен содержать хотя бы по одному символу из строк numbers, letters, title_letters, specials.
Если вводится символ, не содержащийся ни в одной из переменных выше, то должна выводиться фраза "Prohinited symbol".

Я хотел бы, чтобы в случае ввода запрещенного символа, программа предлагала вводить password до тех пор, пока "пользователь" не введет что-либо, где не будет содержаться запрещенный символ, и только после этого проводилась проверка остальных условий.

Задач на ввод пароля удовлетворяющего условию тут вроде полно было, поищите поиском

Ваш первый цикл составлен неверно. Если проверять на допустимость использованных символов, то как-то по другому. Например:
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass()
while any(letter not in vocabulary for letter in password):
    print('Prohibited symbol used')
    password = getpass()

Попутные замечания:

Ветка else для циклов имеет смысл, если возможен ранний выход через break. У вас этого нет, поэтому condition1 лишен смысла.

Условия condition_ лучше делать логическими. В последней проверке сравнение на равенство единице сработает только для последнего условия, остальные все равно будут преобразованы в bool. Вам этого достаточно.

Проверку на надежность лучше делать как-то по другому, например через словарь. Это даст возможность компактно указать на изъяны текущего пароля.


Как бы я изменил код:
from getpass import getpass

char_groups = {
    'ascii lowercase': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'ascii uppercase': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    'digits': '1234567890',
    'punctuation': '!@#$%^&*()-+',
}
valid_characters = ''.join(char_groups.values())

print('Use:', valid_characters)
password = getpass()
while any(ch not in valid_characters for ch in password):
    print('Invalid character used.')
    password = getpass()

weaknesses = [f'no {group_name}' 
              for group_name, group_chars in char_groups.items()
              if not any(ch in group_chars for ch in password)]
if len(password) < 12:
    weaknesses.append('length < 12')
if weaknesses:
    print('Password is weak:', ', '.join(weaknesses))
else:
    print('Password is strong')


Спасибо большое!

@ГеоргийКокоев Размышление вслух, которое вас ни к чему не обязывает. Если хотите поблагодарить, то это лучше делать либо проголосовав за ответ, либо отметив ответ как решение. Это лучше, чем устная благодарность, поскольку повышает репутацию отвечающего и предоставляет больше возможностей по модерации сайта. К тому же это предрасполагает отвечать вам в будущем. К примеру, я смотрю на поведение спрашивающего. Если человек задал десяток вопросов, получил хорошие ответы, но ни один не выбрал как решение, то предпочитаю ему не отвечать.
